# c# database return value handling

Tags: c#, oracle

Assuming I have a function in Oracle:

```
function pass return int
IS
BEGIN
return 213;
END;
```

And I want to add a parameter of the return value with NO actual name, `parameter.Add("hello???", OracleDBType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;`  . How should I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Em, this approach requires a parameter's name in " " , and I don't know what to put in there. If i had an actual name, that will work .

Comment: The name of the parameter that gets the return value is ignored. Name it whatever you like. Something unlikely to cause confusion like `RETURN_VALUE` seems apposite.

Comment: in oracle if your function isn not doing any dml then you can call the function as a select statement.  create or replace function pass return int
IS
BEGIN
return 213;
END;

then if you run select pass from dual you get 213

Comment: well it's not seems to be ignored :  System.ArgumentException: Parameter '@ReturnValue' not found in the collection.

Comment: Show actual code.

Answer (score 1):

solved :
parameter.Add("ReturnValue", OracleDBType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

Comment: Something to note for the future, if you add parameters to your Oracle function in the future, the `returnvalue` parameter must always be the first one specified in the collection for oracle to acknowledge it.